# Compare configuration data text with a default data text

Tags: python, text, compare, comparison, text-files

I am in the process of understanding how to compare data from two text files and print the data that does not match into a new document or output.

### The Program Goal:

- Allow the user to compare the data in a file that contains many lines of data with a default file that has the correct values of the data.
- Compare multiple lines of different data with the same parameters against a default list of the data with the same parameters

### Example:

Lets say I have the following text document that has these parameters and data:
Lets call it Config.txt:

```
<231931844151>
Bird = 3
Cat = 4
Dog = 5
Bat = 10
Tiger = 11
Fish = 16

<92103884812>
Bird = 4
Cat = 40
Dog = 10
Bat = Null
Tiger = 19
Fish = 24

etc. etc.
```

Let's call this my Configuration data, now I need to make sure that the values these parameters inside my Config Data file are correct.

So I have a default data file that has the correct values for these parameters/variables. Lets call it Default.txt

```
<Correct Parameters>
Bird = 3
Cat = 40
Dog = 10
Bat = 10
Tiger = 19
Fish = 234
```

This text file is the default configuration or the correct configuration for the data.

Now I want to compare these two files and print out the data that is incorrect.

So, in theory, if I were to compare these two text document I should get an output of the following: Lets call this Output.txt

```
<231931844151>
Cat = 4
Dog = 5
Tiger = 11
Fish = 16

<92103884812>
Bird = 4
Bat = Null
Fish = 24

etc. etc.
```

Since these are the parameters that are incorrect or do not match. **So in this case we see that for <231931844151> the parameters Cat, Dog, Tiger, and Fish did not match the default text file so those get printed. In the case of <92103884812> Bird, Bat, and Fish do not match the default parameters so those get printed.**

So that's the gist of it for now.

### Code:

Currently this is my approach I am trying to do however I'm not sure how I can compare a data file that has different sets of lines with the same parameters to a default data file.

```
configFile = open("Config.txt", "rb")
defaultFile = open("Default.txt", "rb")

with open(configFile) as f:
    dataConfig = f.read().splitlines()

with open(defaultFile) as d:
    dataDefault = d.read().splitlines()

def make_dict(data):
    return dict((line.split(None, 1)[0], line) for line in data)


defdict = make_dict(dataDefault)
outdict = make_dict(dataConfig)

#Create a sorted list containing all the keys
allkeys = sorted(set(defdict) | set(outdict))
#print allkeys

difflines = []
for key in allkeys:
    indef = key in defdict
    inout = key in outdict
    if indef and not inout:
        difflines.append(defdict[key])
    elif inout and not indef:
        difflines.append(outdict[key])
    else:
        #key must be in both dicts
        defval = defdict[key]
        outval = outdict[key]
        if outval != defval:
            difflines.append(outval)

for line in difflines:
    print line
```

### Summary:

I want to compare two text documents that have data/parameters in them, One text document will have a series of data with the same parameters while the other will have just one series of data with the same parameters. I need to compare those parameters and print out the ones that do not match the default. How can I go about doing this in Python?

### EDIT:

Okay so thanks to @Maria 's code I think I am almost there. Now I just need to figure out how to compare the dictionary to the list and print out the differences. Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
for i in range (len(setNames)):
    print setNames[i]
    for k in setData[i]:
        if k in dataDefault:
            print dataDefault
```

obvious the print line is just there to see if it worked or not but I'm not sure if this is the proper way about going through this.

Comment: can you update your data example so that it exhibits the problem and explain which entries should/should not match

Comment: @scytale I edited and added it to the original post to show which parameters didnt match and why.

Comment: ok, and how is your code not behaving correctly?

Comment: Well the code just matches the lines rather than matching the parameters, in other words my if the default has 5 lines, and my config has 15lines it only compares the first 5 lines with the first 5 lines of config.

Comment: @JeanP If the config data file is always going to have those entries separated by a blank line, you should try parsing the file so that you keep them separate. Make a data structure which stores the label of the set of values and has a dictionary for the values. While the file isn't empty read everything up to the next blank line and parse it accordingly.

Comment: @Maria Could you send me some resources so i can study up on that? Im fairly new to python in general Im not sure how to do that or maybe my lingo is still new and i dont understand it too well

Comment: @JeanP Instead of doing split lines, just do a read() and then do custom processing on the input (also beware of the size of your file when calling read without a parameter). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split and try passing \n\n or \r\n\r\n as the delimiter.
Optionalyl process each line in the dataConfig one by one until you reach a blank entry (just \n or \r\n).

Comment: @Maria I thought using split lines to split the different sets/series of parameters in my config file would allow me to compare them individually to the default file

Comment: @JeanP what version of Python are you using? I'll write you some sample code.

Comment: @Maria Currently using 2.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code for parsing the file into separate dictionaries. This works by finding the group separators (blank lines). setNames[i] is the name of the set of parameters in the dictionary at setData[i]. Alternatively you can create an object which has a string `name` member and a dictionary `data` member and keep a list of those. Doing the comparisons and outputting it how you want is up to you, this just regurgitates the input file to the command line in a slightly different format.

```
 # The function you wrote
 def make_dict(data):
    return dict((line.split(None, 1)[0], line) for line in data)

# open the file and read the lines into a list of strings
with open("Config.txt" , "rb") as f:
    dataConfig = f.read().splitlines()

# get rid of trailing '', as they cause problems and are unecessary
while (len(dataConfig) > 0) and (dataConfig[len(dataConfig) - 1] == ''):
    dataConfig.pop()

# find the indexes of all the ''. They amount to one index past the end of each set of parameters
setEnds = []
index = 0
while '' in dataConfig[index:]:
    setEnds.append(dataConfig[index:].index('') + index)
    index = setEnds[len(setEnds) - 1] + 1

# separate out your input into separate dictionaries, and keep track of the name of each dictionary
setNames = []
setData = []

i = 0;
j = 0;
while j < len(setEnds):
    setNames.append(dataConfig[i])
    setData.append(make_dict(dataConfig[i+1:setEnds[j]]))
    i = setEnds[j] + 1
    j += 1

# handle the last index to the end of the list. Alternativel you could add len(dataConfig) to the end of setEnds and you wouldn't need this
if len(setEnds) > 0:
    setNames.append(dataConfig[i])
    setData.append(make_dict(dataConfig[i+1:]))

# regurgitate the input to prove it worked the way you wanted.
for i in range(len(setNames)):
    print setNames[i]
    for k in setData[i]:
        print "\t" + k + ": " + setData[i][k];
    print ""
```

Comment: Okay i think im getting the understanding of this, Could I grab those setData[i] and some how compare it with the default file? Since, by what i understand, setData[i] holds the values for the parameters (cat, dog, bat, fish, and tiger).

Comment: Yeah, setData[i] has a dictonary for the setName[i], so in your example, if setName[i] were <231931844151>, then setData[i] would be { 'Bird': 3, 'Cat': 4, 'Dog': 5, 'Bat': 10, 'Tiger': 11, 'Fish': 16 }, and you could use it like a normal dictionary. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries.

Comment: Ahh okay so the next step in my case would be: **1.** Grab the setData[i] from the default text.  **2.** Compare the two setData[i] dictionaries and return the results that are different or do not match. **3.** Print those results to a output text. 

Would this be a good way of going about it or would you have something else in mind?

Comment: You don't need to store the default text in those lists. You could have a separate dictionary for the data from default. Also, you'll want to compare each setData against the defaultData, and then you can output as you please. You seem to have the general idea though.

Comment: what would be a short way to compare defaultData list to the setData[i] dictionary?

Comment: There's no way to avoid a linear search because you need to look at each character. Depending on how much detail you need, you could short cut though. For example, if you see that your config file has more parameters than the default file has, you could just output an error and stop searching that one. But if you want to output everything, you should iterate through all the keys in the default set, checking if they're in the config set and outputting them if they're not or they don't match. Similarly, output any pair which is in the config set but not in the default set.

Comment: Okay I edited my original post with my current part of the comparison code between the dictionary and the list.  Would this be a good way of going about it?

Comment: okay just trying to figure out how to finalize it to make it work since i am not getting a result from it at the moment. Thank you again I will mark this as Best Answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use those dicts and loop through them to compare?

```
for keys in outdict:
    if defdict.get(keys):
        print outdict.get(keys)
```